# dynamically convert string to HTMLControl in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am having one id of textbox in form of string & I want to set some value from js. How could I set it

```
document.formid.getElementByTag("input").getelementId("strTextId").value = dynamicVal
```

Other cases its HTMLInputObject ref. But here I am having string id only

Please guide me. I wanted to do it in javascript only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly (questionable), you want to set the text property of a textbox. If that's correct, here's how you do it:

```
document.getElementById("strTextId").value = dynamicVal;
```